# IMAP doesn't connect to the mailbox

Tags: g1ant

I’m trying to read mails from an Exchange server for a specific g1ant account. 
I want to use mails to provide as attachment to g1ant files to process and instructions for processing them.
But when I try to connect to the mailbox I receive this exception:

> The folder is not currently open in read-write mode.

I'm using the following syntax:

```
mail.imap host <servername> login <user> password <password> result ♥emails sincedate ♥yesterday
```

Any suggestions to solve the issue?
Salvatore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the exception. Although it is thrown, the emails are retrieved correctly.

In order to just ignore it, use `errorcall` argument and create an empty procedure like in the following.

```
mail.imap imap.gmail.com login ♥login password ♥password result ♥emails sincedate ♥yesterday ignorecertificateerrors true errorcall IgnoreError

foreach ♥email in ♥emails
    dialog ♥email
end

procedure IgnoreError
end procedure
```